# How to read Hexadecimal correctly

Tags: hex

My book says 0010 1010 in binary notation equals to 42. Then if you use hexadecimal you can break that down into 2A. My book says

> 2 = (2 * 16 = 32) A = (10 x 1 = 10) so 32 + 10 = 42

I'm totally lost. I don't understand, if you're starting from the right to left, why the values of the first four digits are  2 + 8 = 10 = A. Why is then 32 equal 2 and not 32. Aren't you counting the totals?

And why are you multiplying 10 by 1 and then 2 by a different value of 16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each digit in a binary number has weight = 2 ^ position where position starts from right to left. These are weights for byte

```
128 64 32 16   8 4 2 1
```

So for the following number in binary notation

```
  0  0  1  0   1 0 1 0
```

we get

32 + 8 + 2 = 42

Comment: also explain hexadecimal that may be helpful

Comment: if you  have 1111 1111 1111 1111 would you get FFFF? Am I correct to think each block is independent of the other? For example, right most 1111 uses decimal and the other three blocks use 128, 64, 32, 16? The second from the left block does not  does not use 2048, 1024, 512, 256 but instead 128, 64, 32, 16. Is that correct. Sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: 1) there is no decimals, just forget it 2) higer byte in your example starts with pos #8, this is (right to legt) 2 ^ 8 = 256, 2 ^ 9 =512 ... That is 00000001 000000001 = 257

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal: `2A`

```
16    1

2     A          =(16*2)+(10*1) //A equals 10 in decimal
```

In decimal it would be like that:

Decimal: `42`

```
10    1  

4     2          =(4*10)+(2*1)= 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculating complete set. Starting from right to left

Each digit is multiplied with 2^n series from right to left

Its like

```
 first digit  * 2^0
 second digit * 2^1
 Third digit  * 2^2
```

The sum of above results will be calculated

In simple pattern

```
...16  8  4  2  1
```

So answer for your pattern is

```
0+0+32+0+8+0+2+0 = 42
```